# Область видимости переменной

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = 11;

    $('.operator').click(function(){
        alert(input);
        var input = 12;
    });
});
```

Почему alert выводит undefinded?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/326385#326398

Answer (score 5):

[[@alvoro](/users/14981/alvoro)](/users/14981/alvoro) все правильно сказал, а я попробую на пальцах с юмором

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = 11; // опа, объявилась переменная input

    $('.operator').click(function(){ // так-с, кликаем
        alert(input); // input уже инициализирована, попробуем вывести.. хотя стоп, в контексте функции тоже есть переменная input, значит глобальная мне нахрен не нужна. У меня есть родная локальная =) Но... Она ниже alert-a, значит на момент вызова она undefined
        var input = 12;
    });
});
```

UPD: в javascript помимо "подъема" функций есть еще "подъем" переменных. Этот пример очень хорошо описывает "подъем" переменных.

Answer (score 2):

[Очень короткий пересказ этой статьи](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-javascript-the-core/)

Потому что дело обстоит так. Перед непосредственным выполнением функции, javascript (интерпретатор) проверяет объявления переменных (в ней) с оператором var. Если находит такие, то присваивает им undefined. Если не находит, то "ворует" из контекста "повыше". Надеюсь понятно выразился.

В вашем случае, input "еще" undefined, на момент вызова.